# What are the little ovals in Pokemon Amie?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

When you go to decorate and you drag certain items little oval things appear.

When you drag a Poke Puff there is a single oval in the middle which is the only place you seem to be able to place Poke Puffs.

The picture below shows the two ovals that appear when dragging a cushion.

What are these Ovals?

[image: Ovalssssss]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are just predetermined positions for those items.  Like if you are connected to the internet or your friends Pokemon visit your Pokemon Amie those circles are where their Pokemon sit.  So these are the locations that the cushions should be.

The Poke Puff goes in the middle so all Pokemon can share. :)

Comment: So everything outside of those three spots are just for decoration? (btw 3 visiting pokemon gave me that pokepuff! ^ ^)

Comment: Yeah I mean you can decorate any of the other areas just circles are where visiting Pokemon sit and enjoy a tasty snack!

Comment: The items don't seem to lock into place on those spots. Do they just have to be as much on top of it as possible?

Comment: @Kecoey they should lock on when you put them down. It has to be fairly close to the spot to make it work

Comment: @BenBrocka They don't lock into place any more than they do throughout the rest of the screen. This is the closest I can get: http://i.imgur.com/ygeRNQO.jpg

Comment: Oh, that should work though. You'll know it's right when the pokemon sit on the pillows (your pokemon won't, but visitors will)

Comment: They seem to be but they stay to the left, right and above the puff instead of on the cushions I put on the ovals. Oh well. Sorry I forgot to accept!